# What should I configure to send mail on the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, email, mail-command, mail-transport-agent

I am working in the computer at home I want to send me an email and I tried:

```
uuencode all.sh all.sh | mail mymail@gmail.com
```

But the problem is that nothing arrive to my email, I just get the following error:

```
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

The fact is that I use the same command in the work and it works well I would like to appreciate any suggestion to fix this problem. I am not sure If a have to set up any file before to use that command line in my personal computer.
I tried also with installing mutt:

```
mutt myemail@gmail.com < all.sh
```

but I got the following error:

```
sendmail: Cannot open mail:25
Error sending message, child exited 1 ().
Could not send the message.
```

Comment: What is your mail server on the machine?  (`postfix` used on most distros today, or maybe `dovecot`, I believe it is used by ubuntu).

Comment: Yes in fact I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS,

Comment: I have a question, Do you mean that I need to use mutt instead mail?

Comment: I tried that but I got an error i added it to the description of the problem to be more clear.

Comment: The main idea that I would like to achieve is to send and email to my account from my terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic `mail` command is only a mail reader and composer, it doesn't know how to talk to a server over the network (with the [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP) protocol). Talking SMTP is the job of a [MTA (message transfer agent)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). The default MTA on Ubuntu is Postfix. To configure Postfix, run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

If you only want to send mail and not receive any, choose “Satellite system”.

Note that unless you have a permanently-connected machine, with suitable DNS entries, and preferably with a static IP address, you can't directly receive mail: you have to use an external server, and then fetch the mail using a protocol such as IMAP.

Ubuntu includes several versions of the `mail` command. The [heirloom-mailx version](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html) does know how to talk SMTP. You configure it in `~/.mailrc`. The configuration might look something like this:

```
set smtp=smtp.example.com
set smtp-use-starttls
set smtp-auth-user=neo33
set smtp-auth-password=swordfish
```

Comment: Just one question where can I find this file ~/.mailrc I mean in what directory? and shoud I put my email in the line called: set smtp=smtp.example.com ?

Comment: @neo33 `~` means your home directory. The settings in the file are not your email address (you put that in the `From` header), they're the SMTP settings for your mail provider.

Comment: Yes I see, to configure that do I have to create that file at the home level?

Comment: Nowadays [`s-nail` might be a better solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295167/349837)