# How to set up local Windows directory in WSL correctly?

Tags: files, directory, search, windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-search

I ran this script in Windows Subsystem for Linux at the command line. I wanted to search for the latest files but I got the error message "no such file or directory", and so I wonder how do I change my script to make it work?

Here's my script:

````
# Set the path to the directory where you want to search for the latest file
directory="C:/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/*.csv"

# Get the current date in the format YYYY-MM-DD
echo CURRENT_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d) 

# Set the variable to hold the name of the latest file
latest_file="" 

# Find all files in the specified directory whose name starts with "MNSUP"
echo files="$(find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -name "MNSUP*")" 

# Sort the files by modified time, with the most recently modified file first
echo files="$(ls -t $files)" 

# Set the first file in the list as the latest file
echo latest_file="$(echo "$files" | head -n 1)" 

# Check if the latest file contains the current date in the file name
if [[ "$latest_file" == *"$CURRENT_DATE"*.csv ]]; then
  # Print a message if the latest file matches the current date
   echo "$latest_file TODAYYYYY."

else
  # Print a message if the latest file does not match the current date
  echo "$latest_file"

  # Send an email to the user
  echo "The latest file is not present and was not sent to MN.Please re run the job" | mail -s "Latest File Error" "$anna.nguyen@companyname.com"    
fi 

# Print the latest file
# echo "The latest file currently in the folder is: $latest_file"```
````

Comment: Hello Anna Nguyen. How did you run the script? Is this really under Windows Command shell or did you mean you ran it under WSL?

Comment: Why do you have `echo` statements in front of the variable assignments?

Comment: @roaima I ran it under WSL. This is my first time using Unix, I thought I have to put echo in front of $ sign in order to execute it, I'm not sure how to fix my entire script to make it work

Comment: `echo` writes its text to the screen. Remove those statements where you don't need them

Comment: it often helps to show the full error message you get. Because, it usually mentions the offending file, too. Here, I guess you don't have a directory called `C:/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/*.csv`, so that part can't work. Maybe you meant `find "$dir" -name "*.csv" ...` ?

Comment: @ilkkachu it is the same directory I used to run my Python script, but when I switched it to Unix, the error message shows me "no such file or directory"

Comment: Just an FYI, WSL is Windows Subsystem for Linux. Linux is not UNIX.

Comment: @roaima I already removed it but I still get that "no such file or directory" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short summary:*

Change:

```
directory="C:/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/*.csv"
```

to

```
directory="/mnt/c/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/*.csv"
```

---

*Explanation:*

Without having tested the entire script, the `No such file or directory` message is almost certainly coming from the initial `find` command.

The problem is that, when running WSL, you are in *Linux*, which uses an entirely different way to access files and directories than Windows.

> `directory="C:/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/*.csv"`

... is a Windows path.  Linux has no concept of a `C:\` (or even `C:/`) drive.  I see that you have tried to convert the Windows backslashes to forward slashes, which is a good first start, but the path is still invalid.

It's easiest to test this *without* using a script by simply running the following in your Bash shell:

```
directory="C:/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/*.csv"
ls $directory
```

You'll still get a `No such file or directory` error.

What you need to do is access the directory through the *mount* that WSL automatically creates for you for each Windows drive (e.g. `C:\`).  That's going to be (by default) at:

```
/mnt/c
```

So try the following:

```
directory="/mnt/c/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/*.csv"
ls $directory
```

This should work.  You can then update your script accordingly.

*Please note:*  Accessing files on the Windows drives from WSL2 is currently *significantly* slower than for files directly in the Linux ext4 filesystem that WSL creates.

For more information:

- Microsoft Doc: [Working across Windows and Linux file systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems)
- Ask Ubuntu: [Where is WSL located on my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1380253/1165986)
- Several other questions across Stack Exchange, although I couldn't find a good duplicate here on U&L.

Comment: I was able to run the script now, after modifying my directory. But then I tried to use the mail command to email myself but after I ran the script, I have not received new email from me

Comment: Have you configured your mail server in Linux to be able to send to an external SMTP server?  See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299505/432493) (and probably others).

Comment: Since it seems to have solved *this* question, please remember to accept this answer to close it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Yea since I ran on my local machine, I could not email myself. Your answer solved my original question so I will accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AnnaNguyen Thanks - And if that other answer doesn't address the mail issue for you, let me know.  We can look at opening a new question (but reference the other one).

Comment: Since the user is using a wildcard `*` in the path (and assuming is using bash) I would change `ls "$directory"` to `ls $directory`. If you quote the variable it will take the path literally as `/mnt/c/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/*.csv` (the path will not be expanded). And this can cause an error unless a file called `*.csv` exists under `/mnt/c/Users/nguyen_q/Downloads/Test files/`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Good catch (and I *knew* I should have tested that quoting more extensively, but skipped it) - Thanks!